# Is there any way to make Adobe Reader comments more compact?

Tags: microsoft-word, adobe-reader, comments

Currently, my comments are like:

[image]

Is there any way to make them more compact, much like Word's comment function?

Edit: is there any other app more suited to annotations? My two requirements are a) the highlighted text is linked (via arrow, line etc.) to the comment, and b) the comments are constantly viewable, i.e. I do not have to click to open a comment.